# $A \leq_p {\overline{A}} \Leftrightarrow {\overline{A}} \leq_p A$

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

I want  to prove that $$A \leq_p {\overline{A}} \Leftrightarrow {\overline{A}} \leq_p A$$. Does anyone have a Idea how to solve this ?

Comment: What did you try? Starting from the definition of $\le_p$ might help.

Comment: Mytry
If A is  pr educing to A complement it means that a polynomial time function f exists which maps for each w in A w to the complement of A and for each w not in A it maps w to something not in  the complement.

Or more precise: $\forall w \in A, f(w) \in A^\complement$. And $\forall w \notin A , f(w) \notin A^\complement.$. And since $\notin A^\complement = \Sigma^*/A^\complement = A$ we do now have found a polynomial time function for polynomial time reductin $A^\complement$ to $A$. Its the same function both cases(A to complement and A(Complement) to A). Thx !! I  think I got it now.